# Keyboard not working in login screen

Tags: release-hera, greeter, keyboard

Recently I installed Elementary OS Hera on my Dell XPS 9570 and it seemed to be working perfectly fine until I ran into this problem: my keyboard is not responding in Greeter and I cannot login into the system. `CTRL+ALT+F2` does not work too. Mouse and OS seem to be working fine.

Being a complete beginner here I suppose I need to reinstall input drivers, but I have no idea how to do that without keyboard.

Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling the system?

Comment: Can you plug in a USB keyboard to troubleshoot it?

Comment: @Segfault Yes. The external keyboard is not responding as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a day of suffering, I finally managed to find a solution. These are the steps that you want to do if you have a similar problem:

1. Boot into Elementary OS live USB.
2. Mount root partition and proc, dev, sys subsystems of the installed OS.
3. Start bash with `chroot /mnt/hdd /bin/bash` command. `/mnt/hdd` is your mount.
4. Copy `resolv.conf` from live usb to mount.
5. Install Xserver package `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`.
6. Reboot.

My keyboard started working normally after that. I was following [this](https://serverfault.com/a/857480) answer.

Comment: thanks. just for the sake of completness, to copy `resolv.conf` use `cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/hdd/etc/resolv.conf` from a non chrooted shell.